# CSOM - setting the custom list name, when attempting to receive list data

Tags: client-object-model

With the following code, how do I know what list I am retrieving data from?

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

....I pulled this code directly from here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: man, someone is really out to get me today...I don't know why....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's retrieving from the "Announcements" list

```
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');
```

Comment: ok, I assumed that was the title field within a particular list.  thank you for assuring me that is the title of the list itself!  Thanks